# Infinite scrool will load screen position in last appended element

Tags: jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

I wrote this code that appends some new ellements everytime the user scrools down to the a trigger ellement. The problem is that when new ellements are appended, the page is scrooled to the last new ellemnt. I want them to be loaded after the bottom of the visible area (the last position the user had scrolled)What should I do?

```
<script>


var isActivated = true;
var count = 1;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var hiddenPostsWrapper = $('.hidden-posts-wrapper');
  var lastBox = $('.hidden-posts-trigger');
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
  var lastBoxOffset = lastBox.offset().top;

  if (scrollPosition + windowHeight >= lastBoxOffset && isActivated) {
    // Set the flag to false to prevent immediate activation
    isActivated = false;

    // Execute the code here when the user has scrolled to hidden-posts-trigger
    console.log("Scrolled to the last .box element!");
    $(".loading-animation").addClass("active");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".loading-animation").removeClass("active");

      var boxWrap = $('<div class="box-wrap"></div>');
      // boxWrap.addClass("hidden");
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        callData(count); // Once at the bottom of the page -> call 5 times
        count++;
      }
      boxWrap.appendTo('.hidden-posts-wrapper');

      boxWrap.addClass("active");
    }, 200); // Delay the re-activation of the function

    setTimeout(function() {
      isActivated = true;
    }, 1600);
  }
});

function callData(counter) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    
    url: "https://random-word.ryanrk.com/api/en/word/random",
    success: function(result) {
      var newBox = $('<div class="box"></div>');

      newBox.appendTo('.box-wrap');
    },
    error: function(result) {
      console.log("error");
    }
  });
}



</script>
```